# Is it possible to set properties when entering a TODO in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, todo

I want to achieve something similar to [this](http://orgmode.org/manual/Tracking-TODO-state-changes.html#Tracking-TODO-state-changes) where entering a TODO or WAIT state allows you take note. Instead, I want to make a `PROPERTIES` where the value is the heading. For example, if I have a heading called "TODO A" and if I mark it with `TODO` state, is it possible for org-mode to create `PROPERTIES` where the key is `TODO_NAME` and the value would be `TODO A`?

My main purpose of doing this is because when I have a bunch of subtasks that need to be done, I would like to see to what task those subtasks belong in the agenda view.

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22888785/is-it-possible-to-get-org-mode-to-show-breadcrumbs-in-agenda-todo-list) question, on showing breadcrumbs for agenda items.

Comment: Does this fall under `org-agenda-custom-commands` like described [here](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ChrisMcMahan)? Or do I just `setq org-agenda-prefix-format`?

Comment: Oh, I think I figured out the difference. The former changes prefix format locally while the latter changes globally. Am I correct?